# Sorting a Storyblok GraphQL Query

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js, storyblok

I have the following query that queries my storyblok CMS:

```
{
  allStoryblokEntry(filter: {field_component: {eq: "blog"}} ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        content
        published_at
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to sort my nodes however, say by published_at date.
I don't know how to do this though. GraphiQL suggests a `sort` parameter, which I somehow cannot get to work though. [Storyblok tells me](https://www.storyblok.com/docs/api/content-delivery#examples/ordering/order) to use `sort_by=name:asc` - which my GraphiQL doesn't recognise at all, and which also gives me a syntax error. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
{
  allStoryblokEntry(
    filter: {field_component: {eq: "blog"}}
    sort: { 
      fields: name, 
      order: ASC}){
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        content
        published_at
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To sort elements in GraphQL you need to provide a valid `field` (don't need even to query it) and a sort order (`ASC`/`DESC`).

You can check for further information in [Gatsby's GraphQL reference](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/).